# Optimize sub-queries in select statement columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below query has two sub-queries in select statement and those are getting executed for each row. This is very inefficient and is there any way to optimize this in SQL Server?

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
(
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.status,
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 tt.code from text_view tt  where tt.act_id = t.id   ORDER BY tt.created_dt DESC) IN ('A', 'B', 'C','D','E') THEN
      (SELECT TOP 1 created_dt from text_view tt where tt.act_id = t.id  ORDER BY tt.created_dt DESC)
    ELSE
      NULL
  END as notedate,
  (select top 1 created_dt from act_mail tm where tm.act_id = t.id order by created_dt ASC ) AS [mail_dt], 
FROM activity t
WHERE  t.status not in ('CLOSED', 'ACT', 'CANCELED')
) q
WHERE q.notedate is not null
```

Comment: Are you sure the DBMS is executing the subqueries for each row? The DBMS doesn't have to execute a query exactly the way you have written it. We just tell the DBMS what to select, not how to select it. In an ideal world, the DBMS would always come up with the same optimal execution plan, no matter how much we re-write the query. Usually more important than how to write a query is to provide the appropriate indexes. But, well, SQL Server's optimizer is not optimal of course, so re-writing the query may also help :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a join approach here:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT code, created_dt, act_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY act_id ORDER BY created_dt DESC) rn
    FROM text_view
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT created_dt, act_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY act_id ORDER BY created_dt) rn
    FROM act_mail
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    a.status,
    CASE WHEN t1.code IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') THEN t1.created_dt END AS notedate,
    t2.created_dt AS mail_dt
FROM activity a
LEFT JOIN cte1 t1
    ON t1.act_id = a.id AND t1.rn = 1
LEFT JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t2.act_id = a.id and t2.rn = 1
WHERE a.status NOT IN ('CLOSED', 'ACT', 'CANCELED') AND
      t1.code IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') AND
      t1.created_dt IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `NOT EXISTS` to find the latest record from the `TEXT_VIEW` table and then use `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to get the minimum date from `ACT_MAIL` table as follows:

```
SELECT
    T.ID,
    T.STATUS,
    TT.CREATED_DT AS NOTEDATE,
    MIN(TM.CREATED_DT) AS MAIL_DT
  FROM
         ACTIVITY T
      JOIN TEXT_VIEW TT ON TT.ACT_ID = T.ID
      LEFT JOIN ACT_MAIL  TM ON TM.ACT_ID = T.ID
 WHERE
    T.STATUS NOT IN ( 'CLOSED', 'ACT', 'CANCELED' )
       AND TT.CODE IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' )
       AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
          FROM
            TEXT_VIEW TTIN
         WHERE
                TTIN.ACT_ID = TT.ACT_ID
               AND TTIN.CREATED_DT > TT.CREATED_DT
    )
 GROUP BY
    T.ID,
    T.STATUS,
    TT.CREATED_DT
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select activities the latest text view of which has a code A-E. Probably the simplest method to get the latest text view is a `CROSS APPLY` (aka lateral inner join).

You also want to know the oldest mail date. This is just `MIN(created_dt)`. You could get this with an `OUTER APPLY` (aka lateral left outer join), but as this is about a single column, you can just as well keep this in your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.status,
  ltv.created_dt,
  (SELECT MIN(created_dt) FROM act_mail am WHERE am.act_id = a.id) AS mail_dt
FROM activity a
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP(1) *
  FROM text_view tv
  WHERE tv.act_id = a.id
  ORDER BY tv.created_dt DESC
) ltv
WHERE a.status not in ('CLOSED', 'ACT', 'CANCELED')
AND ltv.code IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
```

As for a well performing query, you may want these indexex:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON activity (status, id);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON act_mail (act_id, created_dt);
CREATE INDEX idx3 ON text_view (act_id, created_dt, code);
```